# IntelliJ shortcut isn't working even after setting it in the Keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I've set a keyboard shortcut in Keymap to invoke "Data Source from URL" action. Note that I've checked that only this action has `Cmd Shift S` assigned to it:

[image]

You can see the only shortcuts that conflict with the Mac System. And `Cmd Shift S` is not among them:

[image]

I can't invoke this action using the keyboard shortcut. I've tried configuring other shortcuts but it didn't work. Note I can invoke it from the Action search popup:

[image]

[image]

However, I want to do it with a keyboard shortcut.

I am used to configure keyboard shortcuts in IDEA. Action responsiveness never happened to me when using IDEA. I am wondering why this action keyboard shorcut configuration isn't responsive?

Answer (score 2):

It should work and seems to be a bug. Please, file a [new issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) and provide complete [logs archive](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: Thanks! It's done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247820
I hope It'll be resolved because I rely much on that action.